# FTP timeout on Google App Engine

Tags: python, google-app-engine, ftp, google-app-engine-python

I have been running a Google App Engine website for half a year, which once every day connects to a FTP server to either upload or download files. It usually takes 3-8 tries to do this task, because it gets quite a lot of timeouts. End of last month, it started to get timeout every time, and I do not know why.

To my knowledge, there has been no changes to the FTP server or to the website. The log files on the FTP server shows a login but no activity after login. The website is running on Python 2.7 on US servers. The FTP server is placed in Denmark and support passive FTP mode.

When I run a local copy of the site from my computer (in Denmark), the connection works just fine. When I connect from Google App Engine but to a different FTP server (also in Denmark), the connection also work fine. So I cannot reproduce the unstable connection, except when running on US App Engine servers to that specific FTP server in Denmark.

I use the ftplib library and run the following commands:

```
session = ftplib.FTP()
session.connect(FTPSettings['server'], FTPSettings['port'])
session.login(FTPSettings['username'],FTPSettings['password'], '')
session.cwd(dirname)
filelist = session.nlst()
...
session.retrbinary("RETR " + filename, csvfile.write)
```

It used to fail sometime on either nlst or retrbinary, but now it fails on nlst every time. I have tried both active and passive mode without luck.

Can it have to do with Google/firewalls/EU/US/etc.? Hope somebody have a solution or can guide me in the direction of one,
Thanks.

Comment: Do you see anything suspicious in App Engine logs?

Comment: No, only that i receive a timeout from the nlst command exactly 1 minut after it is sent